# Is it possible to fetch a HTTP resource using App Inventor for Android SDK?

Tags: android, http, app-inventor

I haven't found a component in this SDK that allows me to access a specific URL. The only related component is the TinyWebDB that answers only to a specific protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest release of App Inventor has a Web component, so it's no longer to mess with TinyWebDb.

Update: I wrote [a tutorial](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/tutorials/stockquotes/stockquotes.html) for the Web component.

Answer (score 0):

I have devised a workaround which consists of modifying the TinyWebDb server to act as a proxy for such requests.